# floatingpoint comparing in javascript

Tags: javascript, floating-point, compare

how is this posible that  100 >= 99.2 is false?

```
var ls = parseFloat(("100").replace(",", ".")).toFixed(1);
var val = parseFloat(("99,2").replace(",", ".")).toFixed(1);
alert(ls >= val); /*=> result is false  ...but it should be true */
```

ui culture is nl-BE

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Ed6VY/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`toFixed` results in a string. Strings are compared character-by-character. `"9"` comes after `"1"`, so `"99.2"` is greater than `"100.0"`.

Comment: @OP; You can verify the fact that it's a string by using `alert(typeof ls);`

Comment: more explained here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2283566/tofixed-returns-a-string-in-javascript