# Is it possible to cast NaN from "NaN" (string) ( using toFixed() )

Tags: javascript, double-precision, tofixed

So I got why [to fixed returns a String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2283566/tofixed-returns-a-string-in-javascript), with this in mind is it possible to cast the "NaN" string into NaN to keep the following expression workable?

```
var numberWithPrecission = (1*"A").ToFixed(2) || 0;
```

Comment: Exactly as stated in the question... with the exact same question I linked

Comment: You should probably test for `NaN` at the earliest point possible (on the `"A"`) instead of trusting that it is a number and testing for `NaN` later down the line.

Comment: try `(parseFloat(whatever) || 0).toFixed(2)`

Comment: @thg435 Beautiful! how did i miss that! make it an answer please!

Comment: @Jonathan: no need, just accept yours own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested:

```
var numberWithPrecission = (1*"A" || 0).toFixed(2);
```

Comment: `parseFloat(whatever.toFixed())` doesn't make sense