# JavaScript multiplying by 100 giving weird result

Tags: javascript, multiplication

I have:

```
var a =  0.0532;
var b =  a * 100;
```

b should be returning 5.32 but instead it's returning 5.319999999999999. How do I fix this?

JSFiddle here:
http://jsfiddle.net/9f2K8/

Comment: Here is a solution:

```JavaScript
function moveComma(val, moveCommaByInput) {
  if (val || typeof val === 'number') {
    const valueNumber = Number(val);
    const moveCommaBy = moveCommaByInput || 0;

    if (isNaN(valueNumber)) {
      return null;
    } else {
      return Number(`${valueNumber}e${moveCommaBy}`);
    }
  }

  return null;
}
```

Comment: I've solved this by
`var b = a * 1000 / 10;`

Answer (score 20):

you should use [`.toFixed()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed)

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/yashhy/vJeD8/)**

```
var a =  0.0532;
var b =  a * 100;
b.toFixed(2);     //specify number of decimals to be displayed
```

Comment: I don't know if I'd make the assumption `2` is safe as an argument for `.toFixed`. What if `a = 0.53245239934`? or `b = 10`?

Comment: @naomik if `a = 0.53245239934` will return `0.53` and `10.00` for b

Comment: I'm just saying you might not want to make the assumption that `2` is an acceptable precision just because you wouldn't lose data in this specific scenario.

Comment: Number.prototype.toFixed is a function designed to format a number. It returns a string. If you need a number not a string, have a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/29494612/228770

Answer (score 14):

This is not an error.

Javascript is trying to represent `5.32` with as much precision as possible. Since computers don't have infinite precision, it picks the closest number it can: `5.319999999999999`.

**If your problem lies with numerical operations**, you should be able to add/multiply/etc these numbers without problem. They so close to the intended number that results will be within a negligible margin of error.

**If your problem lies with comparing numbers**, the common approach is to ditch `==` and instead compare using a defined margin of error. For example:

```js
// Two previously obtained instances of the "same" number:
a = 5.32
b = 5.319999999999999

// Don't do this:
if (a == b) {}

// Do this instead (hide it in a function):
margin = 0.000001
if (Math.abs(a - b) < margin) {}
```

**If your problem is visual**, you can use `toFixed()` to create a rounded human-readable string:

```js
number = 123.4567
number.toFixed(2)
> '123.46'
```