# javascript trying to drop the decimal

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'm trying to format `65.32` to become `6532`

`65.32 * 100` gets me `6531.999999999999`.

Why does it do that? Is it a bug? Should I change it to a string and use string manipulation instead?

Comment: welcome to the wonderful world of 64 bit arithmetic.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: Depends on what you're doing, but you could just treat as a string and a remove the period ?

Comment: @Ivar thanks got it on the why, what's the most recommended solution? I can treat it as a string and remove the period yeah. Is that the way to go?

Comment: @Harry Like adeneo said, it depends on what you are doing. You can use `.toFixed()` as [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21472828/js-multiplying-by-100-giving-wierd-result) ([and here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21693552/wrong-value-after-multiplication-by-100), [and here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14490496/how-to-multiply-in-javascript-problems-with-decimals)). That being said, I get the same result on Firefox and Edge. It doesn't seem to be Chrome specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, if you're dealing with numbers it's usually better to stick with numbers.  It makes your code more readable and easier to follow. The Math library provides what you need.

```js
var x = 62.29933;
console.log(x*100);
x = Math.floor(62.29933*100);
console.log(x);
x = Math.ceil(62.29933*100);
console.log(x);
x = Math.round(62.29933*100);
console.log(x);
```