# Decimal number gets disapper

Tags: javascript

My code:

```
var $label = $(ev.currentTarget);
var $price = $label.parent("form").find(".oe_price .oe_currency_value");

if (!$price.data("price")) {
    $price.data("price", parseFloat($price.text());   //price is 10.30 but it returns 10.3 as number
}

$price.html($price.data("price")+parseFloat($label.find(".badge span").text() || 0));
/* The value coming in **badge** is **12.00**
 * but parseFloat converts that into **12**
 * thats why after the addition I got the output as **22.3**
 * but i want it as **22.30**
 */
```

I have a string

> '10.30'

Now, if I convert the string to number using parsefloat

> parseFloat('10.30')

I got the output as **10.3**

And If I do it using the .tofixed(2)

> parseFloat('10.30').toFixed(2)

I got the output **10.30** but it is in **STRING** which is the big problem for me because I want the output as **number**.

And if i do like this

> Number(parseFloat('10.30').toFixed(2))

I got the output **10.3**

But i want the output in number and with decimal point
like this 10.30

Plz help...!!!

Comment: The number `10.3` is precisely the same as `10.30` so why does it matter, numerically? If it's for presentation in a web page then a string is fine.

Comment: The last digit is a 0, its irrelevant for floating point calculations to have it included. When you output something, it becomes a string anyway, so what's the problem exactly?

Comment: Please Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2221167/javascript-formatting-a-rounded-number-to-n-decimals/2909252#2909252

Comment: @DavidThomas ::>  Ya, I knw that the last digit is zero. But, in my case its very much important. Its for the ecommerce website and in product price I have to display the decimal.

Comment: Also, using floats for prices might not be the best idea.

Comment: Please demonstrate a case where string is inpropriate (especially you said you need to use it in **display**) and a zero-padded number is necessary.

Comment: @Passerby   Edited the comment by adding my code. Plz have a look and help if u can. :(

Comment: @ParaMeterz `$price.data("price",parseFloat($price.text(),10).toFixed(2));`

Comment: @ParaMeterz Or if you only cares about the `.html()` call: `$price.html(($price.data("price")+parseFloat($label.find(".badge span").text() || 0,10)).toFixed(2));`

Comment: @Passerby  OMG..!!! thankz thankzzz a lot **Passby** You saved my day. thankz..

Comment: @Passerby  I tired that code also but i was doing like this $price.html(($price.data("price")+parseFloat($label.find(".badge span").text() || 0)).toFixed(2));

I was not placing that **0,10**

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46985/discussion-between-parameterz-and-passerby)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thankz **Passerby**  for the help.

Finally i got the result from this :

> $price.html(($price.data("price")+parseFloat($label.find(".badge span").text() || 0,10)).toFixed(2));

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
parseFloat(Math.round(num3 * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);
```

[See Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/FQTqk/7/)

Comment: Thankz for help. But I had checked that demo and the code of yours but the output coming is in string. :(
But I wanted in number.
The situation is this when we use .tofixed() it will convert the number into string. :(

Comment: No man it didn't fixed.
I want the final output as number not string.
If was use .toFixed() it will convert the output to string.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what are you doing, but I've done the same and got desired result.

My code:

```
var str = '10.30';
var flo = parseFloat(str);
alert(flo);
flo = flo.toFixed(2)
alert(flo);
```

See here: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/K2v3L/)

Comment: Checkout the last alert man the typeof(flo) is string, but i wanted number.
alert(typeof(flo));

Comment: Yes, I saw this...Actually `toFixed()` always converts float to string...check here : http://stackoverflow.com/q/2283566/2764279

Comment: If you want a `number` as `10.30`, than it doesn't matter if it is `10.30` or `10.3`, and if you want to display it somewhere then `String` is fine for that.

Where are you actually using this???

Comment: Ya, I knw that the last digit is zero and doesn't matter. But, in my case its very much important. Its for the product price I have to display the decimal.

And in this case I have to add two fields price + discount and both the things are coming as string. So, for that i have to first convert them into number than i can add. Thats why I want the output  in number with decimal 0. :(