# javascript number precision without converting to String

Tags: javascript, decimal, rounding

I am developing a REST API and returning JSON. One of the fields is called submissionPercent and I need it to be a number but with exactly 2 decimal places

- If the submissionPercent is 20, I need to return 20.00.
- If the submissionPercent is 20.238, I need to return 20.24.

But submissionPercent should be a number **not** a String.
If I use `toFixed` or `toPrecision`, then what I get is a String.

If possible, how do I achieve this?

Comment: `20.00` is just the same number as `20`.

Comment: No 20.12 would just remain as-is

Comment: `someNumber = +(someNumber).toFixed(2);` [Source](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2283566/tofixed-returns-a-string-in-javascript)

Comment: You need to differentiate between formatting a number and storing a number. The two are quite different.

Comment: @arahant , ik , i was  explaining to Bergi

Comment: @kei, neither the +(num).toFixed(2) nor the (num.toFixed(2))/1 trick works from the link you mention. :(

Comment: @LeeTaylor, Yes looks like this is not possible

Comment: `+(someNumber.toFixed(2))`

Comment: Numbers are painful in JS. I suggest you use something like [bignubmer.js](https://github.com/MikeMcl/bignumber.js) for money related or precision sensitive calculations.

Comment: @elmigranto Unfortunately I don't think that is the issue in this question. Otherwise it's a very good library.

Answer (score 5):

```
var n = 20.238;

Math.round(n * 100) / 100
// => 20.24
```

Or more generally:

```
function roundWithPrecision(num, precision) {
  var multiplier = Math.pow(10, precision);
  return Math.round( num * multiplier ) / multiplier;
}

roundWithPrecision(20.238, 2)
// => 20.24

roundWithPrecision(20.238, 1)
// => 20.2
```

As others have pointed out, `20` and `20.00` are exactly the same, so if you want the user to see two digits after the decimal point even if they're zero, you'll have to use a string formatting function like `toFixed`.

In the case of a JSON API, it's up to the consumer to decide how to store the value upon decoding it. Even if you were to output JSON that said `{ val: 20.00 }` a consumer will store it with whatever width it chooses. It might end up in a 32-bit float or a 64-bit float. It might end up in a string. It might end up in a MySQL database in a `VARCHAR(6)` column. You can't control how the consumer treats your data, and this is by design.

There is no advantage to outputting `{ val: 20.00 }` over `{ val: 20 }` or `{ val: 20.00000 }` or `{ val: 2000e-2 }`. If you want the API consumer to *assume* two digits of precision, you should put that information in your API documentation. I would encourage this, as it will help other developers make decisions when implementing API clients.

Comment: yes. but for 20 it gives me 20 not 20.00, as I was hoping was possible.

Comment: Note:  multiplying, rounding and then dividing reduces the usable numeric range, if you require large precision numbers.

Comment: "20.00" is only possible format as a `String`, which is what @Bergi was trying to explain.

Comment: @arahant In what context? In every sense, `20` *is* `20.00` and vice versa. `var num = 20` is *exactly* the same as `var num = 20.00`

Comment: @arahant In the case of a JSON API the consumer will decide how to represent the number internally. This is by design. If you want to ensure that a developer writing an API client knows to expect non-integer values you should include that information in your API documentation.

Comment: @Jordan, yes I know 20 and 20.00 is the same. I just was wondering if it was possible to have it returned as 20.00

Comment: @arahant See my updated answer. In a JSON API there is absolutely no advantage of having `20.00` instead of `20`.

Comment: Throw Js into the fire, this is such an abhorrent shortcoming.  Oh, hi there, Python!