# Convert 0 to 0.00 as number

Tags: javascript

I am trying to convert numbers in following formats

```
0 -> 0.00
1 -> 1.00
1.1 -> 1.10
4.0  -> 4.00
```

But problem is its returning as string only

```
value = 0;
var s = Math.floor(value / 60) + "." + (value % 60 ? value % 60 : '00');
console.log(s+s); //just checking if its number
```

But its returning as string , I tried parseInt , but its returning only 0 . I tried `ParseFloat and fixedTo(2`) , its returning as string only.

Comment: If you format a number for display it becomes a string. There's no other way.

Comment: @Rajesh  : it returns string

Comment: `0` and `0.00` are _literals_ representing the same number value. You cannot get a Number _literal_ by definition; only a string. It's not clear, though, what exactly you're trying to do here.

Comment: You can convert the string into number using the `Number` function i.e. Number('1.10') return 1.1 as number, but you cannot maintain the format you want.

Comment: why do you need this kind of *"numbers"*?

Comment: Take a look to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2283566/how-can-i-round-a-number-in-javascript-tofixed-returns-a-string), maybe it will help you

Comment: I want to pass this number to a function to make my slider work , that function is not accepting this strings

Comment: I am using nouiSlider

Comment: it looks, that *nouiSlider* is working with numbers. for display, like [this](https://refreshless.com/nouislider/examples/#section-non-linear), it uses `toFixed` method.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As seen in the comments, there is no way for that in JavaScript. Formatting a Number always returns a Srting. For this you have some possibilities, though

```
Number(1).toFixed(2) // "1.00" - setting the number of digits after the decimal point
Number(1).toPrecision(2) // "1.0" - setting the number of digits
```

These are for printing it out, so normally, it shouldn't matter if it is a String or a Number.

Then if you want to use it as a Number, you just follow @Max 's advice and convert it using the function `Number(str)` or the shorthand `+str`.

Comment: Its not for printing , Its for passing to another function

Comment: What is that other function has to do with formatted numbers, may I ask? In my mind if a function needs a Number it is all the same if it gets it formatted or not. But perhaps I lack a bit of imagination...