# Error: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number' with toFixed()

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have simple function of calculating the sum of numbers and strings in columns in  a table. The sum works well and gives me results. The issue is that the sum has a lot of decimal places and I want to convert it to 2 decimal places, whenever I try

```
return sum.toFixed(2);
```

I end up with an error.

> Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.

Example of the sum from some columns

```
615.7142868041998, 0,10, 34.0476188659667, 14.761905193328857
```

What I have so far. The table columns contains both integers and strings, am using the reducer function to get only numbers

```
getSum(columnNumber) {
    let sum = 0;
    const columnNumberToPropertyMap = [
      "id",
      "teamNumber",
      "rural",
      "completed",
      "entirehouseholdabsent",
      "postponed",
      "refused",
      "vacant",
      "dwelling"     
    ];
    const property = columnNumberToPropertyMap[columnNumber];
    return this.rural.reduce((acc, curr) => {
      //const adder = Number(curr[property]) || 0;
      const adder = isNaN(Number(curr[property])) ? 0 : Number(curr[property]);
      sum = acc + adder
      return sum.toFixed(2);
    }, 0);
  }
```

How can I convert the sum to 2 decimal places. I have tried to pipe the result in the html `| number : '1.2-2'` it is not working also . thank you in advance

Comment: `sum.toFixed(2)` returns a string. You should add types to your functions to find such errors much faster: `getSum(columnNumber: number): number {`

Comment: keep track of your datatypes. javascript doesn't care, but typescript does. keep track if you are using strings or numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to do the .toFixed after all the numbers have been summed, stick it after the reduce:

```
return this.rural.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  //const adder = Number(curr[property]) || 0;
  const adder = isNaN(Number(curr[property])) ? 0 : Number(curr[property]);
  sum = acc + adder
  return sum;
}, 0).toFixed(2);
```

Answer (score 2):

`.toFixed()` converts the `number` into a `string`, that's why you are getting the error. You can convert it back to number like

```
parseFloat(sum.toFixed(2))
```

You can also create a utility function like

```
const formatDecimalNumber = (
    num: number,
    decimalPlacesToKeep = 2,
): number => parseFloat(num.toFixed(decimalPlacesToKeep))
```

**Update**

As pointed out in the comment, this is not a perfect solution. It all comes from the complexities of floating point math (not only limited to `JavaScript`). There's very good discussion [in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken).

On the other hand, `.toFixed()` is more like an utility function that rounds off and/or adjusts a number for easy representation. See [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) here.

Some alternatives to this is approach is discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2283566/2563833).

Comment: You might want to add *why* [`.toFixed` returns a string...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken) which will also be a problem with your idea of parsing it back to a float...